# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in Android after database encryption using SQLite Cipher

Tags: android, serial-port, sqlcipher-android

**I have been using Serial Ports and Biometric libraries in my android app successfully before adding SQlite cipher. After implementing an encrypted database...I am suddenly getting this exception. Not sure of the cause even after spending a long time.**

Here is the stack trace I am getting.

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.billing.app-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.billing.app-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.billing.app-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.billing.app-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libserial_port.so"

The error says - couldn't find "libserial_port.so"

I have already included the .so in jniLibs as shown in image.

[image]

Here is how my app.gradle looks

```
            implementation 'com.github.felHR85:UsbSerial:3.3'
            implementation files('libs/ePOS2.jar')
            implementation files('libs/CH34xUARTDriver.jar')
            implementation files('libs/serialport.jar')
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
            implementation 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.2.0@aar'
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an other folder named `armeabi-v7a` in `jniLibs` and copy all `*.so` file in it.

This solved my problems.